# Python: How to Resize Raster Image with PyQt

Tags: python, image, pyqt, resize, aspect-ratio

I need to find a way to re-size an input raster image (such as jpg) to a specified width/height resolution (given in pixels). It would be great if PyQt while resizing a new image would keep an original image's aspect ratio (so there is no stretching but scaling only).

src = '/Users/usrName/Images/originalImage.jpg'  (2048x1024) (rectangular image 2:1 ratio)
dest= '/Users/usrName/Images/originalImage_thumb.jpg'  (64x64) (output image is square 1:1 ratio).

Thanks in advance!

#### POSTED RESULTED FUNC:

...could be used to resize and to convert an image to any format QT supports so far... such as: 'bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pbm', 'tiff', 'svg', 'xbm'

```
def resizeImageWithQT(src, dest):
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(src)
    pixmap_resized = pixmap.scaled(720, 405, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dest)): os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest))
    pixmap_resized.save(dest)
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Create a pixmap:

```
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(path)
```

and then use [QPixmap.scaledToWidth](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#scaledToWidth) or [QPixmap.scaledToHeight](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#scaledToHeight):

```
    pixmap2 = pixmap.scaledToWidth(64)
    pixmap3 = pixmap.scaledToHeight(64)
```

With a 2048x1024 image, the first method would result in an image that is 64x32, whilst the second would be 128x64. Obviously it is impossible to resize a 2048x1024 image to 64x64 whilst keeping the same aspect ratio (because the ratios are different).

To avoid choosing between width or height, you can use [QPixmap.scaled](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#scaled):

```
    pixmap4 = pixmap.scaled(64, 64, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

which will automatically adjust to the largest size possible.

To resize the image to an exact size, do:

```
    pixmap5 = pixmap.scaled(64, 64)
```

Of course, in this case, the resulting image won't keep the same aspect ratio, unless the original image was also 1:1.